# Javascript detect table cell border?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a javascript maze game, and in order to stop the character when it reaches a wall, I need to use an `if...else` statement to detect the cell borders. For example:

```
var blah = document.getElementById('hi').style.border-right;

if(blah==20px) {
    my function
}
```

Is this possible? If so, then how? Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea, but it will get you the `border-right` style value of the `id=hi` element

Answer (score 0):

```
function getBorders(el)
{
    return ["Top", "Right", "Bottom", "Left"].map(
       function(v) { return el.style["border"+v+"Width"]; });
}

var b = getBorders(document.getElementById('hi'));
// b is an array with border-width strings (or empty strings)
// in the css order top, right, bottom, left——access with subscripts 0-3
```

Comment: I can understand what this does, but how do I add it to my code? my example is at http://thomaswd.com/maze.